# Bold format with mathematical expression in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, fonts

I have problems in using tex expression into matplotlib and putting them into bold format. I cannot at the moment find a solution.

Here is a minimal example. How can I put the subscripts, superscripts and the greek-letters into bold format ?

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)

x = np.arange(10)

first_plot,  = plt.plot(x[:],2*x[:],'k-')

second_plot, = plt.plot(x[:],4*x[:],'k-')

third_plot,  = plt.plot(x[:],6*x[:],'k-')

plt.legend([first_plot,second_plot,third_plot],[r'\textbf{A}$_\sigma$',
r'\textbf{B}',r'\textbf{a$^2$}'], fontsize=36, loc=[0.4,0.70],frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather related to latex than to matplotlib. But for easy cases like this you can use `\boldmath`.

```
[ r'\textbf{A}\boldmath$_\sigma$',
  r'\textbf{B}',
  r'\textbf{a\boldmath$^2$}']
```

[image]

See e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols) on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without `rc('text', usetex=True)`? I would like to keep the font set for the figure and use LaTeX for math only.

Answer (score 0):

For me neither `\boldmath` nor `\boldsymbol` work, but `\mathbf`.